# php group by TIMESTAMP by YEAR not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

What are the different ways to group a query in Zend Framework by timestamp.
What classes can you use and what is the best practice?

Comment: You should provide more code ? What is Sql class ? and `select` method ?

Comment: As you appear to be using a framework or database obfiscation tool of some sort, which one are you using

Comment: I need help with just the group part:
it works when i use:
$select->group('date_create');
but i need to make it work by YEAR, Weeks and Days.
When the column is a timestamp you can make
"GROUP BY YEAR(date_create)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

You have to use an Expression:

```
$select->group(new Expression("YEAR(date_create)"));
```

Comment: So if you had told us that you were using the Zend Framework, _like I asked 20 minutes ago_ Someone might have been able to help you. That is what the TAGS are for, to attract the attention of those people with specific and related skills to your question